# DirectX 11 SDK - where can I download it?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, directx

I'm trying to setup DirectX on Visual C++ 2010 express. 
I do not have the SDK installed and could not figure out where to download it.
I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was also searching for the DirectX SDK and found out this: [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I followed the instructions and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

The DirectX SDK is now obsolete, all DX content is now folded into the Windows SDK but if you've got Visual Studio 2012 and onward it's included already.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363